# Unknown spacing below code and title disappears

Tags: sql, oracle, report, sqlplus

I wrote this code:

```
SET linesize 140
SET pagesize 30
set underline =
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YYYY';

ACCEPT sDate CHAR FORMAT 'A10' PROMPT ' Enter the start date:  ' 
ACCEPT ednDate CHAR FORMAT 'A10' PROMPT ' Enter the end date  :  '

COLUMN customerID FORMAT A8 HEADING "Customer ID "; 
COLUMN fname FORMAT A10 HEADING "First name"; 
COLUMN memberID FORMAT A11 HEADING "Member ID"; 
COLUMN salesdate FORMAT A10 HEADING "Sales Date"; 
COLUMN salesID FORMAT A9 HEADING "Sales ID" ; 
COLUMN countriesName FORMAT A18 HEADING "Countries"; 
COLUMN productName FORMAT A35 HEADING "Product Name"; 
COLUMN totalAmount FORMAT $999999.99 HEADING "Price (yen)"; 
COLUMN subtotal FORMAT $999999.99 HEADING "Subprice(yen)"; 

TTITLE CENTER 'Sales for ' &sDate ' to ' &ednDate'
BTITLE LEFT 'Page No: ' FORMAT 999 SQL.PNO SKIP 2
BREAK ON customerID SKIP 3 ON fname ON memberID 
COMPUTE SUM  LABEL 'Total (Yen): ' OF subtotal ON memberID 


CREATE VIEW salesDateView AS
SELECT s.customerID, c.fname, salesID, co.countriesName, p.productName, s.totalAmount, m.memberID, s.totalAmount*(1-discountAmount) AS subtotal,salesdate
FROM sales s, customers c, member m, list l, discount d, product p,shop sh,countries co
WHERE c.customerID = m.customerID AND
    m.memberID = d.memberID AND
    d.discountID = s.discountID AND
    s.listID = l.listID AND
    l.productID = p.productID AND
    s.shopID = sh.shopID AND
    sh.countriesID = co.countriesID AND
    TO_DATE(salesdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY') BETWEEN TO_DATE('&sDate', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('&ednDate', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
order by customerID,salesdate;

select * from salesDateView;
drop view salesDateView;

CLEAR COLUMNS
CLEAR BREAKS
CLEAR COMPUTES
TTITLE OFF
BTITLE OFF
```

the `TTITLE CENTER 'Sales for ' &sDate ' to ' &ednDate'` didn't display

i tried to modify the spacing between column and test those code before. Those problem appear after i test those code and i can't remove the spacing even i already delate those code from my code.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: The 'unknown spacing' is what's supposed to happen with `btitle` - that ["Places and formats a specified title at the bottom of each report page"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/BTITLE.html) and you've defined your page size as 30 lines, so the final title appears on line 30. That's supposed to happen - it's intended for printing more than screen view really. I'm not sure what you mean about the title disappearing. You've shown one script and three outputs so we can't know what settings you had for the other two.

Comment: Your `ttitle` line has a typo - it previously ended `&ednDate' SKIP -2` which has an extra `'`, and SQL\*Plus reports a missing terminating quote; and currently still ends `&ednDate'` with that extra quote. (You can see on this page that all the text after that is green as it's all part of that not-really string.)  If you do `&ednDate SKIP -2` you get the `-2` part as text. If you do `&ednDate SKIP 2` it will do what I think you want.